# Sort search results by meta_key value

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I really need help with this. Below is a code of my wp page template for search results `search.php` and everything works just fine. Now, the website is about public events so it's very important that search results are displayed by event date. I've created a custom field called "date" and I'd like to display the results by "date" field value.

I spent a whole week to find a solution but unfortunately I couldn't. Please, help me :)

Here is a code:

```
<?php
    global $query_string;
    $query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
    $search_query = array();
    if( strlen($query_string) > 0 ) {
        foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
            $query_split = explode("=", $string);
            $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
        }
    }
    $search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>

<?php if ($search->have_posts()) : while ($search->have_posts() ) : $search->the_post(); ?>

    <!-- loop goes here -->

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Thank you!!!!

Comment: please post the array of `$search_query`.

Comment: is is a custom post type? or you want to search the whole site?

Comment: @Mark i want to search whole site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try something else:

In your `functions.php` or `my-plugin.php`

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'customize_search_page' );

function customize_search_page($query){

    if(!is_admin() && $query->is_search && $query->is_main_query()){
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'your_meta_key';
        $query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
        $query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
    }
    return $query;
}
```

I did not tested it but the `pre_get_posts` filter will be called before the loop. If it's the right query (search and main) I changed the `orderby` to an order by meta value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not? This should work on http://yoursite.com/s=test with the standard `if(have_posts()){ while(have_posts()){ the_post(); /*loop goes here*/ }}` template.

Comment: Sorry, it works. I didn't notice before that you have one extra `>` in your code.
So, the line: `$query->query_vars['meta_key'] => 'your_meta_key';`
should be like: `$query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'your_meta_key';`

Thank you very much!!!!